# Ruby: case statement with =~ && !~ in 'when' condition

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, match

There's a code

```
file_paths = {nature:[], nature_thumb:[]}
```

Elsif version that works fine:

```
 Find.find('public/uploads') do |path|
   if path =~ /.*nature.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/ and  path !~  /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
     file_paths[:nature] << path
   elsif
     path =~ /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
     file_paths[:nature_thumb] << path
     #etc
   end 
 end
```

Case version causes a problem

```
 Find.find('public/uploads') do |path|
   case 
   when path =~ /.*nature.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, path !~ /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/ 
     file_paths[:nature] << path
   when path =~ /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
     file_paths[:nature_thumb] << path
     # etc
   end
 end
```

Putting '&&' instead comma causes a error. Comma works wrong. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the cases:

```
Find.find('public/uploads') do |path|
  case path
  when /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
    file_paths[:nature_thumb] << path
  when /.*nature.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
    file_paths[:nature] << path
  end
end
```

or better in your situation:

```
Find.find('public/uploads') do |path|
  file_paths[
    case path
    when /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/ then :nature_thumb
    when /.*nature.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/        then :nature
    end
  ] << path
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! I should have thought. Thanks for refactor btw.

Answer (score 2):

You case statement should look like:

```
Find.find('public/uploads') do |path|

   case 
       #Surround your statement with parenthesis
       when ((path =~ /.*nature.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/) && (path !~ /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/)) 
         file_paths[:nature] << path
       when path =~ /.*nature\/thumb.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/
         file_paths[:nature_thumb] << path
         # etc
       end
    end
```